# hangman game python able to replace hidden letters but doesn't pick up where it left off

Tags: python, python-3.5

Hi so I'm trying to create a hangman game on python, 
I'm able to reveal the hidden letters when the user inputs a correct letter using this method:

```
def getGuessedWord():
    import re
    guessed = re.sub(r'\S', '_', word)
    l = checkLetterInWords()
    if l == True:
        new = ""
        for index, char in enumerate(word):
            if char == letter:
                new += letter
            else:
                new += guessed[index]
        guessed = new
        print(guessed, "\n")
    return guessed
```

However, when I input another correct letter, it does not reveal where it left off. For example:

The word is watermelon

input: w

output: w_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

---

2nd input: a

output: _ a _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

How do I make the input like

w a _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  ?

I've looked at a bunch of other methods on stackoverflow but none of them worked. Can someone help me figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't import the `re` module every time you run the function `getGuessedWord()`.

Comment: This code snippet is not complete. What is the definition of `word` and `checkLetterInWords()`? Why does function `getGuessedWord` have no parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I restructured this code a bit so that it takes every letter a user guesses and adds it to the word if correct.

```
word = "example"
guessWord = ['-'] * len(word)

def guessLetter(letter):
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c == letter:
            guessWord[i] = letter

print("".join(guessWord)) # -> '-------'
guessLetter('e')
guessLetter('a')
guessLetter('x')
guessLetter('m')
print("".join(guessWord)) # -> 'exam--e'
```

This allows:

- No need for regular expressions (also, generally those are imported
  at the top of a file, not inside a function).
- Shorter runtime. We go through the "----" version of the word only once. In Big O Notation: O(n).
- Shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the last state, I change your code to this:

```
word = "ramin"
letter = 'r'

import re
correct = re.sub(r'\S', '_', word)

def getGuessedWord(): 
    global correct
    if letter in word:
        new = ""
        for index, char in enumerate(word):
            if char == letter:
                new += letter
            else:
                new += correct[index]
        correct = new
        print(correct, "\n")
    return correct

letter = 'r'
print(getGuessedWord())
letter = 'a'
print(getGuessedWord())

# Output:
# ('r____', '\n')
# r____
# ('ra___', '\n')
# ra___
```